# Tabs opened via Hyperlinks in Excel/Word not recognizing session cookies

Tags: asp.net, browser, hyperlink, session-cookies

I have an ASP.Net application with authentication using Cookie session variables. Once the user logs in, they can open new browser tabs for the same application and these are logged in automatically as the session cookie is present.

Clicking on a hyperlink on another web page pointing to a specific page within the application also works fine - there is no login required as the user is already logged in.

However, when a hyperlink to the application *is in a Word/Excel document*, this link does not open the page directly and gets bounced to the Login page instead. If I copy/paste the Url from Word/Excel and paste it in the Url bar on the browser, it works fine.

Any explanation to this behaviour? Does the browser open a isolated session when a link is clicked in Word/Excel?

Edit: It also seems Word/Excel perform their own check before opening a browser tab. If I use a non-existent link, it doesn't open the tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this at my place of work a while back, and found that like you mentioned, MS Office applications indeed do some mysterious stuff behind the scenes. Details on what it actually does are in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/click-hyperlink-to-sso-website

Toward the bottom of that article, they suggest a workaround involving a meta refresh, which is what worked for us. In our case, we added a method to our request pipeline that checks for a Microsoft product in the `User-Agent` header. If found, it sends a meta refresh that triggers the browser to use an existing session rather than trying to start a new session (which is why you're being redirected to a logon page). Here's more or less the code:

```
    private static string MSUserAgentsRegex = @"[^\w](Word|Excel|PowerPoint|ms-office)([^\w]|\z)";
    protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Request.UserAgent, MSUserAgentsRegex))
        {
          Response.Write("<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'/></head><body></body></html>");
          Response.End();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about this. Let me try it and get back.